# Open a Lightbox in a Featherlight.js Lightbox without double-click - Is it possible?

Tags: featherlight.js

I would like to open a featherlight lightbox with some html-content. The content contains some small pictures and I would like to use the featherlight for the images too to show bigger sizes.

For example: I added the link to the image in the ajax examples div from http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/

```
<div class="ajaxcontent lightbox">
    <h2>This Ligthbox was loaded using ajax</h2>
    <p>With <a href="https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#installation">little code</a>, you can build lightboxes that use custom content loaded with ajax...</p><a class="btn btn-default" href="assets/images/droplets.jpg" data-featherlight="image">Image</a>
</div>
```

when the lightbox opens Ihave to double-click on the image/button to let it open.

Is it possible to open it on the first click?

[Example](http://mederano.bplaced.net/test/)

Comment: What have you tried? Live example? Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: Dear Marc-André,

I added above a link to example (Button Ajax My Example)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want to do is open a featherlight, and from the content of that featherlight open a nested featherlight (which seems really odd tbh), you can use the `afterOpen` callback, in which you can open the nested featherlight using `$.featherlight(...)` or `find('.my-button-or-something').trigger('click')`.

Note that when closing the nested featherlight, the first featherlight will still be opened.